# How can I load the Twitter Share Button faster, by calling the script one time instead of X times?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to insert 100 Twitter share buttons in a page for each article.

How can I do this without having to call the Twitter script 100 times?  When doing so with this code the page takes 30 seconds to load, even after using `$(document).ready`

Here's Twitter's script:

`!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id))
 js=d.createElement(s);
 js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");`

And please note I've looked at other questions.  This is not a question of *how to* insert the button multiple times, it's *how to do so quickly* or *by only calling the JS script one time*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too attached to the "100 buttons" approach, you might want to consider displaying the Twitter share button only on the currently active or hovered-over element (article). That way, the UI is much cleaner and you don't need to weigh down the DOM with hundreds of buttons.

Here's a UX pattern used in Asana - display extra controls only on hover. The mouse is over "Get an Android tablet".

[image]

Comment: You can see that pattern in action right here on StackOverflow. Comments will show the upvote arrow only when you hover over them.

Comment: ...and a second comment to show the interaction patters. Any reason for the downvote, BTW?

Answer (score 0):

> Called without argument, widgets-js will again search the entire
>   document.body for uninitialized widgets. For better performance, pass
>   either an HTMLElement object, or an array of HTMLElement objects to
>   restrict the search only to children of those nodes.

Reference - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events